Is it possible to embed airsim in a webpage and provide control of simulation via a web UI?
I am trying to see if I can run the airsim in the background, provide the view via an embedding in a webpage and also provide simple controls to control a drone.
It is for an educational page, where small kids could fly drones.
How would I go about this?
The airsim website has bunch of tutorials on how it is used, but my problem is specifically how I would show the interface in a webpage, so they did not cover.
Controlling the drone seems non problematic as airsim provides apis for that.
